# Permission problems in accessing my local folder

Tags: pdftex, filesystem-access

I am having problems with file permissions in Windows 10.  I am using
TeX Live 2020. PdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX is unable to access files in my local texmf tree. I am getting the following error:

```
Process started: lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "block1".tex

c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/ownsty/answers.sty: Permission denied

Process exited with error(s)
```

I can compile files that do not need access to my local texmf tree. I have checked my permissions. It seems OK to me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the 2020 installer, which has since been solved. The permission problems are with the files, not with the directories. Instructions for fixing texmf-local can be found at http://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html

I repeat them here:

- In File Explorer, right-click the texmf-local folder
- Choose Properties
- Select the Security tab
- Click the Advanced button
- Click the Change permissions button and deal with the resulting UAC prompt
- There is no need to change anything in the box with Permission entries. Instead: Check the checkbox 'Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object'
- Finally, click the OK button and click Yes in the resulting Windows Security dialog.
  -